# Accidental wipe, PLEASE HELP

Tags: wine

Amateur
Running Ubuntu 16.04
Went to completely Uninstall wine to reinstall it bc I couldn't get it to work.
Last command I did was
rm -rf $HOME/ .wine
I thought it froze. Did command
Sudo reboot.
Stupid. It rebooted. I logged in. All my files are gone. Idk what to do

Comment: Looks like you have deleted your home folder (instead of just deleting .wine). The space between `$HOME/` and `.wine` was the culprit. **Don't blindly copy-paste commands from the internet**. Nothing can be done now unless you have a backup. You can either [create a new user](https://websiteforstudents.com/how-to-add-new-users-to-ubuntu-20-04-18-04/) by [logging in as root](https://askubuntu.com/a/24024/124466), or [reinstall Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview) (this may be simpler, since you are probably quite new to Ubuntu).

Comment: Also, if you want to reinstall - 16.04 is going to lose support soon because it is already 5 years old. I suggest you install Ubuntu 20.04 instead (or use a lighter variant like Xubuntu 20.04, in case you have a slightly old computer).

Comment: If you had important data that was lost, can try using testdisk and/or photorec.  It takes time to learn to use them well and no guarantee.  Very important lost data should be recover  by professionals.  Do not touch or use disk if want to recover data.

Comment: Just a reminder 16.04 reaches end of standard support on April 22 2021. You may want to think about upgrading to 18.04 or 20.04. End of Stand Support means no more support or updates. You may not ask questions here either as 16.04 will be off topic. If you sign up for ESM you can still get security patches but that is all.

Comment: Archisman, I was able to get some photos back. Had to go to work, I'll try to get some libreoffice and calc files back tonight. Definitely learned my lesson about blindly copying and pasting, will upgrade to 20.04 when this recovery is done.

Comment: Crip659, I got pictures back in recup_directory using photorec, so excited. I ran it using a USB with 16.04 on it, are those photos recovered now? David, I guess I have 9 days left to figure this out. With what I was able to recover, I don't think I'll need a pro. I don't remember having any seriously import files on that drive.